# ¿como obtener el total de cada registro y al mismo tiempo el monto mensual?

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal comunidad necesito formular la siguiente consulta.
tengo una BD MySQL con los siguientes campos y datos de la tabla solicitudes

```
id_solicitud   nro_trabajo   monto   fecha_retiro
      1             12        1200     2020-05-12
      2              9         200     2020-05-21
      3             12        1550     2020-06-01
      4             20        3200     2020-06-12
      5              9       32200     2020-06-09
      6             12        1350     2020-06-07
```

de la cual necesito obtener el total de lo solicitado en cada trabajo (nro_trabajo) y a la mismo tiempo lo que gasta el mes en consulta obteniendo lo siguiente:

```
Nro Trabajo   monto Total   monto del mes   mes consulta
    9            32400          32200             06
   12             4100           2900             06
   20                0           3200             06
```

lo intenté asi:

```
SELECT SUM(monto) AS monto_total 
FROM solicitudes WHERE MONTH(fecha_retiro)= $mes 
GROUP BY nro_trabajo
```

pero me falta llamar los montos del mes???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con la siguiente consulta:

```
select 
    s.nro_trabajo,
    (select sum(monto) from Solicitudes where nro_trabajo=s.nro_trabajo) 'monto total',
    (select sum(monto) from Solicitudes where  nro_trabajo=s.nro_trabajo and MONTH(fecha_retiro)=6) 'monto del mes'
from Solicitudes s

GROUP BY s.nro_trabajo
```

Answer (score 0):

q tal comunidad, agradezco la respuesta anterior que me ayudó a llegar al final y logre dar con la solución:

```
SELECT s.nro_trabajo, SUM(s.monto) AS suma,
     (SELECT SUM(monto) FROM solicitudes WHERE nro_trabajo=s.nro_trabajo AND MONTH(fecha_retiro)=6)AS monto_mes,
       
FROM Solicitudes s  GROUP BY s.nro_trabajo
```

lo q me devuelde el total acumulado mas lo consumido el mes 06 de cada trabajo

muchas gracias